# looking for a tan- or logit-like function

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I'm looking for function with a tan- or logit-like shape (i.e., like a sideways "s"), that is $y=-1$ at $x=0$, $y=0$ and $x=0.5$, and $y=1$ at $x=1$. I want the function to have a free parameter $\theta$ which controls the "curvedness": $\theta=0$, the function should be a straight line, and as $\theta$ increases the function should become more and more horizontal around $x=0.5$ (such that at $\theta=\inf$, $y=0$ everywhere except at exactly $x=0$ and $x=1$, if that makes sense). Any ideas what such a thing might be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your function is $[0,1]\to [-1,1]$, you could try $$f(x)=(2x-1)\times |2x-1|^\theta = \text{sign}(2x-1)\times|2x-1|^{\theta+1}$$ taking this to mean $f(\frac12)=0$.

For values of $\theta$ in $\{0,1,2,\ldots,20\}$ the curves look like this, though any real $\theta>-1$ would work

[image]