# Elegant way to express this function

Tags: functions

[Previously](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2195494/looking-for-a-tan-or-logit-like-function) I asked for a function with a tan- or logit-like shape that was $y=−1$ at $x=0$, $y=0$ at $x=0.5$, and $y=1$ at $x=1$, which had a free parameter which controlled the "curvedness."

If possible, I would like a similar function with three parameters:
one that controls $y$ at $x=-1$, one that controls $y$ at $x=1$, and a curvedness parameter as before. Also as before, I would like $y=0$ at $x=0.5$.

I've come up with such a function in pseudo-code:

`(2*x - 1) * (-a * (x < 0.5) * abs(2*x - 1)**c + b * (x >= 0.5) * abs(2*x - 1)**c)`

where `(x < 0.5)` is 1 whenever $x< 0.5$ and 0 otherwise, and similarly `(x >= 0.5)` is 1 whenever $x \ge 0.5$ and 0 otherwise.

The function works but I feel like there should be a more elegant way to express it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write
$$
\eqalign{
  & y = \left( {2x - 1} \right)\left( { - a\left[ {x < 1/2} \right]\left| {2x - 1} \right|^{\,c}  + b\left[ {1/2 \le x} \right]\left| {2x - 1} \right|^{\,c} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {2x - 1} \right)\left| {2x - 1} \right|^{\,c} \left( { - a\left[ {x < 1/2} \right] + b\left[ {1/2 \le x} \right]} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {\mathop{\rm sgn}} \left( {x - 1/2} \right)\left| {2x - 1} \right|^{\,c + 1} \left( { - a\left[ {x < 1/2} \right] + b\left[ {1/2 \le x} \right]} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {\mathop{\rm sgn}} \left( {x - 1/2} \right)\left| {2x - 1} \right|^{\,c + 1} \left( {\left( {\left( {{{b - a} \over 2}} \right) - \left( {{{a + b} \over 2}} \right)}
 \right)\left[ {x < 1/2} \right] + \left( {\left( {{{b - a} \over 2}} \right) + \left( {{{a + b} \over 2}} \right)} \right)\left[ {1/2 \le x} \right]} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {\mathop{\rm sgn}} \left( {x - 1/2} \right)\left| {2x - 1} \right|^{\,c + 1} \left( {\left( {{{b - a} \over 2}} \right) + \left( {{{a + b} \over 2}} \right)\left( {{\mathop{\rm sgn}}
 \left( {x - 1/2} \right) + \left[ {1/2 = x} \right]} \right)} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left| {2x - 1} \right|^{\,c + 1} \left( {\left( {{{b - a} \over 2}} \right){\mathop{\rm sgn}} \left( {x - 1/2} \right) + \left( {{{a + b} \over 2}} \right)} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left| {2x - 1} \right|^{\,c + 1} \left( {b\;H\left( {x - 1/2} \right) + a\;H\left( { - \left( {x - 1/2} \right)} \right)} \right) \cr} 
$$
where $[P]$ denotes the [*Iverson bracket*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)
and $H(x)$ the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).

And for the latter you can use one of its analytic approximations.